# Problems transforming a dataset from wide to long with pandas

Tags: pandas, long-format-data, wide-format-data

Consider the following columns of a dataset:

ONOFF_LEVER_V0, ONOFF_LEVER_V1, LEDD_DOPA_V0_categ_1, LEDD_DOPA_V1_categ_1

I'd like to transform this dataset in the long format with columns:

visit (0 or 1, corresponding to V0 and V1 respectively), ONOFF_LEVER, LEDD_DOPA_categ_1

I was thinking of using the pd.wide_to_long function, but the suffix V0 or V1 in my case is not always at the end of the variable. Any advice?  (this is actually a minimal example of my problem, my dataset is huge).

Comment: Kindly provide sample dataframes with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for `MulitIndex`, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
c='ONOFF_LEVER_V0, ONOFF_LEVER_V1, LEDD_DOPA_V0_categ_1, LEDD_DOPA_V1_categ_1'.split(', ')
df = pd.DataFrame(1, columns=c, index=[0,1])

df.columns = [df.columns.str.extract('_(V0|V1)', expand=False), 
              df.columns.str.replace('_(V0|V1)', '', regex=True)]

df = df.stack(0).droplevel(0).rename_axis('visit').reset_index()
print (df)
  visit  LEDD_DOPA_categ_1  ONOFF_LEVER
0    V0                  1            1
1    V1                  1            1
2    V0                  1            1
3    V1                  1            1
```